# emmet combining elements issue

Tags: html, emmet

I am trying to combine the following two emmet snippets, they both work out apart, but I want to combine them. The first one looks like this:

```
header>nav>ul>li{menu$}*4^^^section>(article*2>header>h3{Blog by}^div>p>lorem^footer>p{date:})
```

and the second one looks like this:

```
div>p>a{Next article}^footer>span{Tel:09834234&nbsp;|}+span{&nbsp;email:info@some.se}
```

I want to combine them as one script where the second script follows after the first ones section tag.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to group both?

```
(header>nav>ul>li{menu$}*4^^^section>(article*2>header>h3{Blog by}^div>p>lorem^footer>p{date:}))+(div>p>a{Next article}^footer>span{Tel:09834234&nbsp;|}+span{&nbsp;email:info@some.se})
```

So group2 as a sibling of group1

```
(expr1)+(expr2)
```

Comment: Actually, I want expr2 to be outside expr1, so anything in expr2 should come after the ending tag of section in expr1.
I have tried to use ^ step outside the section tag.

Comment: Maybe you can post your expected result, because for me grouping seems to be the perfect answer. Here expr1 is expanded and </section> is exactly the last tag. Then expr2 is directly expanded afterwards?

Comment: Thanks, I had put my parenthesis in the wrong places :)